# global name not defined error

Tags: python, return, global-variables, function

I keep on getting an error with my discount variable. name-error: global name 'discount' not defined. please take a look at my code and help me out. I don't want to modify the parameters of the functions at all.

```
def finddiscount(quantity):
    if quantity >= 1 and quantity <= 9:
        discount = 0
    elif quantity >= 10 and quantity <= 19:
        discount = .2
    elif quantity >= 20 and quantity <= 49:
        discount = .30
    elif quantity >= 50 and quantity <= 99:
        discount = .40
    elif quantity >= 100:
        discount = .50
    return discount
def calctotal(quantity, price):
    finddiscount(quantity)
    disc = (price*quantity)*discount
    total = (price*quantity)
    due = (price*quantity)-(price*quantity)*dicount
    print ("\t","Order total $",format(total, "10.2"),"\n\t","Discount    $",format(disc,"10.2"),"\n\t","Amount Due $",format (due, "10.2"),sep="")
def main():
    quantity = int(input("How many packages where purchased?"))
    price = float(input("How much is each item?"))
    calctotal(quantity, price)
main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare `discount` as a global if you want to access it in a multi block scope.

```
discount = 0

def finddiscount(quantity):
    ...
    global discount    # Needed to modify global copy of discount
    discount = 1
```

Comment: When i tried to go back and declare it as a global it gave me the error name 'discount' is assigned before global declaration

Comment: can you post the code that shows your original declaration of `discount`?

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown I don't think `discount` is supposed to be a global. There is actually a function call to calculate it in the function throwing the error.

Comment: @Nabla intended or not there is no other way to access it in all those methods unless it is passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
disc = (price*quantity)*discount
```

You never defined `discount` in `calctotal` (and neither in global scope). Assign the result from `finddiscount(quantity)` to it. At the moment you are calculating the discount, but drop the result immediately by not assigning it to any variable:

```
def calctotal(quantity, price):
    discount = finddiscount(quantity)
    disc = (price*quantity)*discount
    total = (price*quantity)
    due = (price*quantity)-(price*quantity)*dicount
    print ("\t","Order total $",format(total, "10.2"),"\n\t","Discount    $",format(disc,"10.2"),"\n\t","Amount Due $",format (due, "10.2"),sep="")
```

Answer (score 0):

If we look at this block of code

```
def calctotal(quantity, price):
    finddiscount(quantity)
    disc = (price*quantity)*discount
    total = (price*quantity)
    due = (price*quantity)-(price*quantity)*dicount
    print ("\t","Order total $",format(total, "10.2"),"\n\t","Discount    $",format(disc,"10.2"),"\n\t","Amount Due $",format (due, "10.2"),sep="")
```

neither `discount` nor `dicount` (I'm assuming typo) have been declared in `calctotal()`. Below should solve yoru issue

```
def calctotal(quantity, price):
    discount = finddiscount(quantity)
    disc = (price*quantity)*discount
    total = (price*quantity)
    due = (price*quantity)-(price*quantity)*discount
    print ("\t","Order total $",format(total, "10.2"),"\n\t","Discount    $",format(disc,"10.2"),"\n\t","Amount Due $",format (due, "10.2"),sep="")
```

**EDIT:**
While making `discount` a global variable is certainly a way to do this, in general I'd recommend not making a variable global unless you have a good reason.  For example - if the discount applied was going to be affected by external functions, and you wanted it changed in `finddiscount()` as well then a global variable would work nicely.  However in this scenario you are creating all possible values of `discount` within `finddiscount()` and it just makes more sense to use assignment.

The problem with global variables is that you can accidentally reassign them to things you didn't intend to do, and it can clutter up the namespace if done for no reason.